# Are there any tools for making irregular polygons regular?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bmesh

Are there any tools in Blender that take irregular polygons and make them regular (approximate a circle)? I'm specifically looking for a solution that works with **preexisting** polygons. Also, it would be nice if it keeps the overall position after making it regular.

#### Irregular Polygons

[image: irregular polygons]

#### Regular Polygons

[image: regular polygons]

Comment: The only built in one I know of is `Alt Shift S` (*To Sphere*). However the looptools addon supports some things which are useful for this, such as automatically spacing out vertices or snapping them into a circle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [LoopTools](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/LoopTools) addon, which is already with the official Blender builds.

Enable this addon from the Add-Ons list, then select the target face, then <kbd>W</kbd> > **LoopTools** > *Circle*, which will distribute vertices **circularly and evenly**.

[image]

Comment: Does this provide any other options?

Comment: Yes, try it out. :) But Circle is exactly what the OP wants, I suppose.

Comment: Well it would still be wise, seeing how the question is worded (and covers more ground than the OP might notice), to mention that Loop Tools can do much more. This makes the question and answer more useful to future visitors.